# Objects appeared in each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a spawn obstacles for a player, and when a game begins, obstacles appear in each other. I tried to solve this problem through the while and physics 2d cycle, but when I started the game, the Unity crashed.
And I also tried through Raycast2D to check when the beam collides with some kind of collider, and change its position. But ray a small didn't always work.

First way

```
 while (!Physics.CheckBox(pos, BlotPref[1].transform.localScale))
    {
         pos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), YPosSetter());
    }
```

Second way

```
 while (hit.collider == null)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), YPosSetter());
    }
```

Spawner

```
private void SpawnerPaper()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < PlaningSpawn; i++)
    {
        if (rndType <= _dbPaperSpawn)
        {
            var blot = Instantiate(BlotPref[Random.Range(0, BlotPref.Length)], new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(30f, 70f)), Quaternion.identity);
            blot.transform.SetParent(paper.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understant you spawn obstacles randomnly? and sometimes your overlap?

Comment: Yes , sorry for my bad english!

Comment: could you show your spawn code?

Comment: Ok, sure one minutes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution is to test collider if obstacles is near the random position with [Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html) and using [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html):

of course obstacles have collider...

```
private void SpwanerPaper()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PlaningSpawn; i++)
    {
        if (rndType <= _dbPaperSpawn)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(30f, 70f));
                 // i have choosen radius 1f, you could increase it if needed
                Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(position, 1f, obstacleLayer);

                if (colliders.Length == 0)
                {
                    //so no obstacles present, spawn here
                    var blot = Instantiate(BlotPref[Random.Range(0, BlotPref.Length)],
                        position, Quaternion.identity);
                    blot.transform.SetParent(paper.transform);
                    break;// get out while loop
                }

                // so  obstacles within 1m of the player loop again and give new random position

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Following the  situation you could use too [Physics2D.CircleCastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCastAll.html)

If you dont know Layers, you have a tutorial youtube [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR-Tf_6uzwc)

Comment: Unity is crushed :D